# Añadir a traves de un formulario objetos a una misma fila de una db Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

**Tengo un models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE
from django.utils.timezone import now

# Create your models here.

class Users(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Projects(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Y un formulario**

```
from .models import Users, Projects
from django import forms

class AddUser(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Users

        fields = [
            'name',
            'email',
            'password'
            ]

        widgets = {
            'name' : forms.TextInput(),
            'email' : forms.EmailInput(),
            'password' : forms.PasswordInput()
            }

class InitUser(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Users

        fields = [
            'email',
            'password'
            ]
        
        widgets = {
            'email' : forms.EmailInput(),
            'password' : forms.PasswordInput(),
            }

class AddProject(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Projects

        fields = [
            'name',
            'date',
            'user_id',
        ]

        widgets = {

            'name' : forms.TextInput(),
            'date' : forms.DateInput(),
            'user_id' : forms.Select(),
        }
```

Mi intención es a través del formulario poder crear un proyecto con n usuarios. Pero solo puedo añadir un único usuario. Por así decirlo añadir colaboradores a un proyecto.

```
class AddProject(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Projects

        fields = [
            'name',
            'date',
            'user_id',
        ]

        widgets = {

            'name' : forms.TextInput(),
            'date' : forms.DateInput(), 
            'user_id' : forms.Select(),<--- 
        }
```

He mirado la documentación en Django pero no encuentro la manera de solucionarlo, había pensado en `selectMultiple` pero no sirve.